# Value of a function with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's assume we have a sampled function `y = f(x)` given by an array of strictly increasing numbers `x`, and an array `y` :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 4, 11)      # [ 0.   0.4  0.8  1.2  1.6  2.   2.4  2.8  3.2  3.6  4. ]
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, -1, -4, -5, -6, -7])
plt.plot(x,y); plt.show()
```

**Is there a natural way, with numpy, to compute the value `f(1.2)` or `f(2.3)` for example?**
*Either by nearest neighboor (`f(2.3)` should be `f(2.4) = -1`) or by linear interpolation.*

[image]

*This method would work, but would be rather unpythonic : first manually find `i` such that the distance `abs(x[i]-2.2)` is minimal, and then return `y[i]`. I can imagine numpy has a built-in function for this?*

Comment: You will have to be more specific about what you mean by *"compute the value `f(1.2)`"*. Strictly speaking, your function is only defined on the values given in `x`, so if you want to estimate the value at some other arbitrary location then you will need to interpolate it. There are lots of ways to perform interpolation, e.g. nearest-neighbour, linear, cubic etc. Take a look at [`np.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) and [`scipy.interpolate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html).

Comment: @ali_m I edited and added that both nearest-neighboor or linear interpolation would be ok for me, as long as it's efficient (I have millions of sample points to process in short time).

Comment: @Basj If nearest-neighbor is OK and performance is an issue, why don't you just round x to the nearest available value? Otherwise your question has effectively been answered in the comment from ali_m, above.

Answer (score 0):

If interpolation for visualization is the goal, simply plotting the function does the trick. Numpy draws lines between data points, which is equivalent to linear interpolation.

However, if you want to work with the interpolated values you can use [`np.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) for linear interpolation or some function from [`scipy.interpolate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) for any type of interpolation. Finally, you can perform nearest neighbor interpolation by simply rounding the index.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 4, 11)      # [ 0.   0.4  0.8  1.2  1.6  2.   2.4  2.8  3.2  3.6  4. ]
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, -1, -4, -5, -6, -7])

xi = np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)

# a) nearest neighbor rounding
dx = x[1] - x[0]
i = np.round(xi/dx).astype(dtype=int)
y1 = y[i]

# b) linear interpolation
y2 = np.interp(xi, x, y)

plt.plot(x, y, '.', label='original points')
plt.plot(xi, y1, label='rounding (nearest neighbor)')
plt.plot(xi, y2, label='linear interpolation')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution given as comment by @ali_m works well :

```
np.interp(1.2, x, y)    # 3.0
np.interp(2.3, x, y)    # -0.5
np.interp(2.4, x, y)    # -1
```